# Prevent mobile Safari from loading the last page when started

Tags: mobile-safari

Whenever I open Safari on both my iPhone and iPad, it starts loading the last webpage that I visited in the past, which is not very convenient.

Is there a way to stop it from doing this?

Comment: What is your desired behavior instead of opening to the last page visited? Opening to a home page? A blank page? Your bookmarks?

Comment: Good point: a blank page I guess, which leaves me free to navigate to whereever i want at that time.

Comment: I am modifying my answer to reflect this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save a bookmark to about:blank (or your desired home page) as an icon in your home screen. Then click that to launch Safari rather than the Safari icon.

To do this:

- open Safari.
- Type the url `about:blank` into the URL area and go to that page. The page will, unsurprisingly, be empty.
- Press the share button, and select "Add to Home Screen"
- Assign a name to this blank page. In your case, you might want to call it Safari.

(Dan Frakes of MacWorld spells out these steps at http://www.macworld.com/article/159303/2011/04/ios_safari_blank_page.html; thanks to [Heng-Cheong Leong](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/568/heng-cheong-leong) for point this out).

Alternately, you could close any pages you had open in Safari before exiting the program.

Comment: Dan Frakes of Macworld.com have written a step-by-step guide on creating the "about:blank" home-screen bookmark at http://www.macworld.com/article/159303/2011/04/ios_safari_blank_page.html